# MVC Handle Null Date from View to Controller

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I have an MVC View which has an *optional* `<input />` for a Date.
The Model (Generated from a DB) has the `DateTime` field as `Not Null`

If the user decides to leave the field blank, the `View` will get passed back to the `Controller`, which will then validate everything and save it away to a DB.

The issue comes in where the *null* value being passed back is either `1900-01-01 12:00:00 PM` OR `DateTime.Min`, depending on the server (Right now two different Dev machines).

The `Min Date` needed in the DB is `1900-01-01 12:00:00 PM`, so to circumvent this, I have the following check:

```
person.PaidDate = person.PaidDate == DateTime.MinValue || person.PaidDate == DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 12:00:00 PM") ? DateTime.Parse("1900/01/01 12:00:00") : person.PaidDate;
```

Is this the best, or most correct way of checking for a *supposedly null* date being brought back from the `Controller` ?

Comment: If `PaidDate` is indeed optional, why not make it nullable by using `DateTime? PaidDate`?

Comment: The `Model` is generated from the `DB`, and its marked as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Why not set the `PaidDate` value on its POCO constructor `PaidDate = SqlDateTime.MinValue` ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra `Cannot convert SqlDateTime to DateTime` - I don't think passing that to DateTime would be any easier than passing a set date to DateTime

Comment: Sorry I meant, `DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 12:00:00 PM")` or `DateTime.Parse(SqlDateTime.MinValue.ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a model binder.

```
public class DateModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var dateTime = bindingContext.Model as DateTime?;
        var result = dateTime.GetValueOrDefault() == DateTime.MinValue 
            ? DateTime.Parse(SqlDateTime.MinValue.ToString()) 
            : dateTime.Value;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Register it in Global asax.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateModelBinder());
```

Comment: If I'm doing this for two pages, would this approach really be necessary though?

Comment: @SemiDemented, this should be applied globally to any DateTime Property of the model or DateTime parameter..